# How do I determine the outgoing port being used by SSH after connecting?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, vnc

I have connected to a remote server using ssh:

```
ssh -i <keypair> <user@server>
```

How do I determine the outgoing port that my ssh client is using to connect to the remote server ?

I want to know so that I can setup my VNC Client to use that port...

NOTE: I am not talking about the port on the remote server!

Comment: Why? The port being used by the outbound SSH connection doesn't have any relevance outside of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the variable `$SSH_CLIENT` - the second number is the client port.

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to know it from the client side, you can run this command

```
lsof -p pid | grep TCP
```

with `pid` being the process ID of the `ssh` command